# EAP-SIM supported?

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch

I got an ubuntu phone on Meizu MX4, and I sometimes need to connect to Wifi hotspot using EAP-SIM authentication mode. For the moment, I did not succeed to connect using this mode.
Is it supported? If no, any idea when it will be available, as it is very conveniance to use it.

Thx
Fab

EDIT: OTA6 release still does not support EAP-SIM authentication mode. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Since the last update my BQ Aquaris E5 supports the following authentication modes:

- “None”
- “WPA Personal”
- “WPA Enterprise TLS”
- “WPA Enterprise TTLS”
- “WPA Enterprise LEAP”
- “WPA Enterprise FAST”
- “WPA Enterprise PEAP”
- “WEP”
- “Dynamic WEP”
- “LEAP”

I believe that is not device specific and the Meizu MX4 should support the same.

See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Networking#Authentication_variations.2C_certificates.2C_and_PAC_files

Comment: Yes mine too. But unfortunetely not the "EAP-SIM" mode!